# Updating Client Woocommerce Shipping Address before checkout page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I would like to popup a simple model on homepage and let a user choose their shipping country before the checkout/cart page.

I made a small select box popup model and then run this function with AJAX in order to change the user shipping country but its not being updated.

// Localizing

```
//*********** Ajax Change shipping country on press ***********/

function localize_array() {

$localize = array(
    'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    'nonce'    => wp_create_nonce( 'yo-ajax-call-ak' ),
);

return $localize;

}

function ajax_change_shipping() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'ak-country-change', get_template_directory_uri() . '/inc/js/select-country.js', array( 'jquery', ), '1.0', true );
wp_localize_script( 'ak-country-change', 'akselect', localize_array() );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_change_shipping' );
```

// The ajax call

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('body').on('change', '.yo-lang-select', function () {

        var select = $(this);
        var value = select.val();
        $.ajax({
            url: akselect.ajax_url,
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                action: 'get_the_defualt_lang',
                value: value
                nonce: akselect.nonce
            },
            success: function (respond) {
                console.log(respond);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);

            }
        });
    });

});
```

// This is the function

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_the_defualt_lang', 'get_the_defualt_lang' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_the_defualt_lang','get_the_defualt_lang' );

function get_the_defualt_lang() {

$lang = $_POST['value'];

add_action( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'set_country_befor_cart_page' );
function set_country_befor_cart_page() {

    WC()->customer->set_country( $lang );
    WC()->customer->set_shipping_country( $lang );

}

$respond = $lang;

echo json_encode( $respond );


die();

}
```

// The popup form

```
<div data-effect="mfp-zoom-out" id="shop-pop_1" class="mfp-hide">
<select class="yo-lang-select" data-type="lang" title="">
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom (UK)</option>
    <option value="US">Other Countries</option>

</select>
```

// Using a hook to insert the from to the shop page

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'ak_store_popup' );

function ak_store_popup() {
  get_template_part( 'template-parts/popups/popup', 'store-main' );
}
```

Comment: I added the code for the form and the hook to get it in the shop page before the check out, hope it helps, thanks for the feedback

Comment: I added it now, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Update:** Tested successfully with some additional changes:
>
> - jQuery: When the page  with the select field is loaded, the 'US' default value is now set through ajax.
> - The select field: Just 2 values are necessary (the default: 'US' | the other: 'GB'). You can add many others.
> - The country is correctly set now (the billing country was necessary).

1) The jQuery code:

There is something particular with Wordpress with `jQuery`, is that the shortland **`$`** doesn't work… So To make it work your jQuery code need to start with: **`jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {`**

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var select = $('.yo-lang-select'),
        value = select.val();

    function ajax_update( value ){
        $.ajax({
            url: akselect.ajax_url,
            method: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                action: 'get_the_defualt_lang',
                value: value
                //nonce: akselect.nonce
            },
            success: function (respond) {
                console.log(respond);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown);
            }
        });
    }

    ajax_update( value );

    $('body').on('change', select, function () {
        value = select.val();
        ajax_update( value );
    });
});
```

2) The HTML Select field:

```html
<div data-effect="mfp-zoom-out" id="shop-pop_1" class="mfp-hide">
<select class="yo-lang-select" data-type="lang" title="">
    <option value="US">United States</option>
    <option value="GB">United Kingdom (UK)</option>
</select>
```

3) The PHP function:

- Now you get the correct response and ajax is working fine.
- The other problem is to use **`set_country_befor_cart_page`** hooked function in `woocommerce_add_to_cart` embeded in your php ajax script as it will never run and will never get the value for **`$lang`**.
- I have added the **billing country** to really set the country mostly for checkout…

So instead just use it this way:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_the_defualt_lang', 'get_the_defualt_lang' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_the_defualt_lang','get_the_defualt_lang' );
function get_the_defualt_lang() {

    $lang = $_POST['value'];

    WC()->customer->set_country( $lang );
    WC()->customer->set_billing_country( $lang ); // Updated HERE Too
    WC()->customer->set_shipping_country( $lang );

    echo json_encode( $lang );

    die();
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This time this is tested and working.

> - As your select field is loaded in a popup, you should maybe need to make some ajustements in jQuery, to handle this event instead.
> - May be you should need to restrict your scripts with `if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {`, **for non logged/registered customers only**.

Comment: the function still does not update the customer country.

Comment: Works fine now, Thanks for the help!

Comment: From my perspective this look good, but when i call WC()->cart->get_cart_shipping_total(); after new shipping country is set i still get the wrong shipping price ...  any hints?

Comment: can i give you +1000000. .this is working awesomely. I was looking for this "WC()->customer->set_...." and I found it here. Thank you bro